# how to echo the words after - character

Tags: php

i have a page and its showing all the names with "**-**" character between them

and i want to just echo the first word before the - character and the second word after the - character

arsenal - liverpool

Betis - Athletic Bilbao

Waasland Beveren - Oostende

### the code i tired

```
                        $arr1 = explode(' ',trim($Event["Event"]["name"]));

                        echo $arr1[0]."\n";
```

but this is just showing the first word , if the first word includes tow names then i cant echo it , i want to echo the full name before and after the - character in tow seprate php

**i want to get this outputs from the examples**

arsenal

liverpool

Betis

Athletic Bilbao

Waasland Beveren

Oostende

Comment: Could you clarify what output you expect to get?

Comment: Have you seen the manual page of [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)? You are separating your string with a space rather than `-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arr1 = explode('-', trim($Event["Event"]["name"]));

$team = $arr1[0];
$town = $arr1[1];

echo "$team - $town";
```

You are using the explode function with the wrong argument value, it should be used with a hyphen (-) instead of a space.

Note this will leave you with leading and trailing spaces, to remove this you can use the trim function:

```
$team = trim($arr1[0]);
$town = trim($arr1[1]);
```

Or put a space before and after the hyphen in the explode function:

```
$arr1 = explode(' - ', trim($Event["Event"]["name"]));
```

This is only the case if your string will always be in the format:

```
<team> - <town>
```

Comment: +1 for using ' - ' (with spaces) as separator. This also handles city names that have hyphens in them correctly

Comment: thank you so much that is exactly what i needed , another thing there are some names like  Waasland-Beveren - Oostende  
how can i handle them too ? i want to echo the Waasland-Beveren

Comment: using the explode function with the first parameter being ' - ' (note the spaces) should yield the results you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

**The explode() function breaks a string into an array.
Note: The "separator" parameter cannot be an empty string.
Use "-" separator in explode function.**

```
<?php
$arr1 = explode('-',trim($Event["Event"]["name"]));

echo trim($arr1[0])."\n";
echo trim($arr1[1])."\n";
?>
```

Comment: you should use " - " as separator for 2 reasons: there is no trailing space after the name, and it doesnt explode Names that have a hyphen in it like "Berlin-Charlottenburg". I know city names rarely have hyphens, but if they do, you are already handling it correctly.